# AWS SQS Delete Messages Using Receipt Handle

Tags: php, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I am trying to set up SQS and after receiving the message, I need to delete it from the queue.

Creating Client -

```
$client = Aws\Sqs\SqsClient::factory(array(
                    'key'    => '******',
                    'secret' => '******',
                    'region' => 'ap-southeast-1'
            ));
```

Sending Message

```
public static function SendMessage()
    {
        if(!isset(self::$queueUrl))
            self::getQueueUrl();

        $command = "This is a command";
        $commandstring = json_encode($command);

        self::$client->sendMessage(array(
                'QueueUrl'    => self::$queueUrl,
                'MessageBody' => $commandstring,
        ));
    }
```

Receiving Message

```
public static function RecieveMessage()
    {
        if(!isset(self::$queueUrl))
            self::getQueueUrl();

        $result = self::$client->receiveMessage(array(
                'QueueUrl' => self::$queueUrl,
        ));

//      echo "Message Recieved >>  ";
        print_r($result);
        foreach ($result->getPath('Messages/*/Body') as $messageBody) {
            // Do something with the message
            echo $messageBody;
            //print_r(json_decode($messageBody));
        }

        foreach ($result->getPath('Messages/*/ReceiptHandle') as $ReceiptHandle) {
            self::$client->deleteMessage(self::$queueUrl, $ReceiptHandle);
        }

    }
```

When I try to delete the message using the Receipt Handle in the receive message code, I get error from Guzzle - 
**Catchable fatal error: Argument 2 passed to Guzzle\Service\Client::getCommand() must be an array, string given,**

Now after searching a lot for it, I was able to find similar questions which state that they were using wrong SDK version. I am still not able to narrow it down though. I am using the zip version of the latest sdk [2.6.15](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/releases/tag/2.6.15)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you give this a try this:

```
self::$client->deleteMessage(array(
    'QueueUrl' => self::$queueUrl,
    'ReceiptHandle' => $ReceiptHandle,
));
```

The *Basic formatting example* in the [API docs for `SqsClient::deleteMessage()`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/latest/class-Aws.Sqs.SqsClient.html#_deleteMessage) (and other operations) should help. All of the methods that execute operations take exactly one parameter, which is an associative array of the operation's parameters. You should read through the [SDK's Getting Started Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/quick-start.html) (if you haven't already), which talks about how to perform operations in general.

Comment: You sir.. are a master.. and I am just a stupid fool!!
I would have read through that a million times but couldn't see my mistake... Thanks a lot